# Split string and in some cases remove

Tags: javascript

I've got a product title which I'm splitting and inserting a linebreak using javascript like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "How are you - doing today?";
    var res = str.split("-").join('<br>');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

This works for most case scenarios, however in some cases I will need to remove the second line completely. So everything after the - will need to be removed. Only within that element though, so if I've got this for example

```
<h3>This is a product - title</h3>
```

the result should be

```
<h3>This is a product</h3>
```

Again this only needs to apply to elements with a certain class. Anybody got any idea ow to do this?

Comment: So you're saying that elements with a certain class need to have the tail removed? Or elements with that class need to be processed and ones with `- title` need the tail removed? You've left large gaps in your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not us a simple replace,

```
string = string.replace(/-/g, '<br>');
```

or for complete deletion, take

```
string = string.replace(/-.*$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `className` of the element:

```
function myFunction() {
    const str = `How are you - doing today?`
    const first = str.split(`-`)[0]
    const all = str.split(`-`).join(`<br/>`)
    const el = document.getElementById(`demo`)
    const el.innerHTML = el.className === `any-name` ? first : all
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
(function() {
  // For splitted titles
  var split = document.querySelectorAll(".dash-split");
  var splits = [];
  
  split.forEach(function(spl) {
    splits.push(spl.innerHTML.split("-").join("<br>"));
  });
  console.log(splits); // Outputs ["This is <br> split!"]
  
  // For removed titles
  var removedEls = document.querySelectorAll(".dash-split");
  var removed = [];
  
  removedEls.forEach(function(rem) {
    removed.push(rem.innerText.split("-")[0].trim());
  });
  console.log(removed); // Outputs ["This is"]
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Welcome!</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 
<div>
   <h1 class="dash-split">This is - split!</h1>
   <h1 class="dash-remove">This is - removed!</h1>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want, provided the script runs at the end of the document. For wrapping, it keys off of the class `title-wrap`.

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <h3>This is a product - title</h3>
  <h3 class="title title-wrap">This is a product - with a wrapped title</h3>
  <h3>This is a product - with another title</h3>
  <script>
  (function() {
   var titles = document.querySelectorAll('h3');
   titles.forEach(function(o, i) {
    var title = o.innerHTML;
    if (/title-wrap/ig.test(o.className)) {
     o.innerHTML = title.replace(/-/g, '<br />');
    } else {
     o.innerHTML = title.replace(/-.*$/g, '');
    }
   });
  })();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```